# Run android networking applications while Wi-Fi is not available

Tags: android, wifi

The device that i am developing have both Wi-Fi and Ethernet. The user may choose to use either ethernet or Wi-Fi interface. However some android application is assuming Wi-Fi connection. Whenever Wi-Fi is not availabe, it will complain "connection lost" or so. 
So without modify the applications themselves, how do I do to make it run with Ethernet while Wi-Fi is not available? Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Try the Android Enthusiasts site instead: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Android. Sorry if I didn't make it clear. I assume I should modify code somewhere to make those Applications think there is Wi-Fi connection while there is not. But I don't know where is the best place to modify, the SDK? the framework? Or anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Check your code for something like

```
protected boolean testNetwork()
{
    ConnectivityManager networkConnectivity = (ConnectivityManager)instance.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final NetworkInfo networkInfo = networkConnectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if ( networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected() ) 
    {
        if ( networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
        {
        }
        else if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET)
        {
        }
        else if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
        {
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This should give you an Idea of how the App is accessing the Internet.

You have to modify the App permissions to access the WIFI states and if you want you can enabled and disable them as well.

Check the [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) class you will get all the available options.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I want. What I want is for example, APK1 needs Wi-Fi connection to be launched. But I don't have source code of it. I assume APK1 is calling SDK API like ConnectivityManager APIs or WifiManager APIs to judge whether Wi-Fi is connected. So I assume what I need to do is to hack those APIs to pretend that Wi-Fi is connected while it is not (in this case ethernet is connected). Because ethernet is connected APK1 should have the connectivity to run its networking stuff. So everything else should be good.

Comment: As the request will be made to Android OS regarding the connection details and OS replies it with the available Connectivity options.


I dont think that it would be possible to fool the other application  from yours that you have the WIFI connectivity when actually you do not.